# How can I undo my voting?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

OK, I precipitated and would like to undo some of my upvotes.

For example, I upvoted the question all answers of:

- [Infopath change Publish Location](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/infopath-change-publish-location#comment38602_17383)

But on an attempt of re-voting, I am getting:

- You last voted on this answer
  Jul 19 at 21:50
  Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited
  (click on this box to dismiss)

Is it possible to re-vote:

- to remove my vote
- to revert the vote (from downvote to upvote or from upvote to downvote)

after voting (downvoting or upvoting)?
and how?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already in your question:

**No, it is not possible** to [unvote or change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046) your mind *unless* the post has been edited. This is due to questions as like to answers.

If you really want to change your mind and vote, you have to do a substantial (aka useful) [edit to this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/you-can-remove-votes-up-or-down-on-questions-that-you-edit?lq=1). Because then this post has been edited...

Usually there is a small amount of time after initial vote, where you can unvote. That means, during this time you can click again and your vote is gone. But I don't know how long this is.

Regarding the fact that this is a general feature for all SE-sites, your questions is "better placed" at [SO-meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). And if you search there, you will find some [long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046) [or](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked?lq=1) [short](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited?lq=1) [discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited?lq=1).

Comment: In that thread I do not have answers (or question), only comments

Comment: @GennadyVanin--ГеннадийВанин It does not matter if you answered anything or not - your vote can only be changed if the question/answer you voted has been changed. Because a change of content can might change your mind about this post. **Nothing else works.**

Comment: Shegit Brahm, thanks but I know that it is not possible. It is a feature-request and support "ticket"/"request". The key-question is "how?"

Comment: @GennadyVanin--ГеннадийВанин I added some links from Meta-SO, where your question is more often seen - but if you ask it from now on, you will get a [closed] as you find it very often discussed.